# i18n.js - Translation message missing... how can I set a fallback value?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I am using the [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) library to internationalize my app.

When a not defined scope is passed to it, it displays a message "missing translation...", and I want to use a fallback value when the scope is not found.

For example:

```
// JSON file
{
    hello: "Hello!",
    fallback: "Ups",
};

// JS CODE
i18n.t("texts.bye"); // Not found...
```

How can I display the texts.fallback of my JSON file if the scope is not found?

Comment: remove the i18next tag... it is not i18next related, but i18n.js

Answer (score 0):

Specify `missingBehavior` option:

```
i18n.t("texts.bye", { missingBehavior: "guess"}); // texts.bye
```

For more, [read here](https://fnando.github.io/i18n/v4.0.0-alpha.14/modules/missingtranslation.html).